# Scaling iframe with form on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i have checkout on my website. And i want to make payment page to be responsive.

I use third party service for payment process. There is an iframe with payment form.

I tried to scale that form using -webkit-transform, but i'v got a bug.

Iframe Input fields are on their old positions (like when oframe wasn't scaled)

Did anyone see this bug? Did anyone know whether there is a possibility to fix the bug?

Comment: Can you submit some code? it would make it easier for someone to help You, not that I can, but I will be facing simular issues too, and may want to follow this question.